# ambiguous function call in children class C++

Tags: c++, ambiguous

I have a question related with the example below:

```
Class A{virtual foo(};virtual g()}; 
Class B: public A {virtual foo();virtual g()};
B::foo(){A::foo()};
A::foo(){g()};
```

When I call B::foo(), it will use B::g() not A::g(), how to explain it, is it because of the 'this' pointer always points to the current object? Thanks a lot!

Comment: -1 for horrible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B::foo()` you are calling `A::foo()`, passing it `this` pointer which points to object of type `B`.

Inside `A::foo()` you're calling `this->g()` which is polymorphic and it will call `B::g()`, because type of `this` pointer inside `A::foo()` is `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Since g() is virtual, it is resolved at runtime. At runtime, this pointer is pointing to B's object and hence g() of B is called